# specifying class directory in ant manifest

Tags: ant, manifest

The manifest stuff in my build.xml looks like this

```
<manifest file="MANIFEST.MF">
    <attribute name="Built-By" value="Me" />
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="LogReporter"/>
</manifest>
```

However my .class files are in another directory basedir/src. Is there a way to specify the directory of the class files? 
Running the current jar gives me a classdefnotfound error.
Also, I'm not looking for the classpath attribute because all the class files are in the same project/jar.

Answer (score 1):

You class files should be in a directory corresponding to their package. For example if the package name is `com.some.package` all class files should be located in a directory `com/some/package`. Consecutively you should refer to your main class with its fully qualified name - for example `com.some.package.MainClass`.

The Java Tutorials contain a good example: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html.

Comment: I fixed the problem with packages, since I was using default packages in eclipse. 
But I got another NoClassDefFoundError: com/MyClass
I'm using eclipse and it puts the class files under ./src and ./bin/com

Comment: You can configure Eclipse where to put the class file by setting the "Default output folder" option in the project's properties (I think it is "Java Built Path" section).